# Having error "Module 'name' resolves to an untyped module at..." when writing custom TypeScript definition file

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.1

I can't find TypeScript definition `@type/{name}` for one of my installed NodeJS packages, so I attempt to write a `d.ts` file for it, and put the file in `{project root}\typings` folder. This is how I do:

```
// My source code: index.ts
import Helper from 'node-helper-lib';


// My definition: \typings\node-helper-lib.d.ts
declare....(something else)

declare module 'node-helper-lib' {
   class Helper { ... }
   export = Helper;
}
```

However, Visual Studio Code keeps yielding this error and puts red line under `declare module 'node-helper-lib'`:

> [ts] Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'node-helper-lib'
>   resolves to an untyped module at '{project
>   path}\node_modules\node-helper-lib\index.js', which cannot be
>   augmented.

Isn't it legit that because the library is untyped, so I should be allowed to add typing to it?

**UPDATE:**

I am using:

- TypeScript: 2.1.4
- Visual Studio Code: 1.9.1
- Node JS: 6.9.4
- Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 108, accepted):

After some tries and errors, I found that `augmentation` means "declaring a module in the same file with other module declaration(s)".

Therefore if we want to write a definition file for an **untyped** 3rd-party JavaScript library, we must have ONLY ONE `declare module 'lib-name'` in that file, and 'lib-name' must exactly match the library name (can be found in its package.json, "name" property).

On the other hand, if a 3rd-party library **already has definition file** `.d.ts` included, and we want to extend its functionalities, then we can put the additional definition in another file that we create. This is called `augmenting`.

For example:

```
// These module declarations are in same file, given that each of them already has their own definition file.
declare module 'events' {
   // Extended functionality
}

declare module 'querystring' {
   // Extended functionality        
}

declare module '...' { ... }
```

I leave my discovery here just in case somebody has same question. And please correct me if I missed something.

Comment: What should I do if a 3rd-party library already has definition file .d.ts included, but I would like to ignore it and use a custom one?

Comment: I'm not sure. Did you try <reference path=".." /> pointing to custom definition?

Comment: I'm trying to write a definition file for a completely untyped npm module, `supertest` — TypeScript's complaint doesn't even make sense, how can I not augment something that doesn't even have a declaration? I thought I've wrote custom definition files like this many times... `[ts] Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'supertest' resolves to an untyped module at '/home/chase/Desktop/projects/formuoli/node_modules/supertest/index.js', which cannot be augmented.` — unfortunately `@types/supertest` is broken by including DOM libraries rendering it broken.. looks like I'm out of luck

Comment: @ChaseMoskal: In your file `.d.ts`, maybe you should just move all the import into the declare module "moduleName" {}.

Comment: @Paleo that was exactly it, all `import` calls must go inside `declare module 'module' {}` scope. the error is misleading at best

Comment: typescript does the same thing if you put the `import` statements required by your module outside of the `declare module` instead of inside it. Such unintuitive odd behavior (sorry for ranting here).

Comment: This answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/48846446/842768

Answer (score 226):

The actual solution is given in a comment by @Paleo in @hirikarate's answer:

**Imports should be declared *inside* the module declaration.**

Example:

```
declare module 'node-helper-lib' {
   import * as SomeThirdParty from 'node-helper-lib';
   interface Helper {
       new(opt: SomeThirdParty.Options): SomeThirdParty.Type
   }
   export = Helper;
}
```

Comment: This is a catch-22. Can't import the `somemodulehere` because it doesn't have a declaration. Can't create a declaration to augment it because it's an `untyped modue`. The example above would be throwing 2 errors. The first being that you cannot augment the `node-helper-lib` the 2nd being that it cannot find the declaration file for the import.

Comment: It may have changed since I wrote that.

Answer (score 9):

The issue for me was that I was trying to declare the module in a `.ts` file. I changed it to `.d.ts` and it all worked just fine.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting that error message too. The issue for me was that I was trying to declare another module in an existing type definition file that had a module declaration in it. After I moved the new module declaration to a new file, the error went away.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it happened with npm 'node-apple-receipt-verify' package:

```
Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'node-apple-receipt-verify' resolves to an untyped module at '/node_modules/node-apple-receipt-verify/index.js', which cannot be augmented.ts(2665)
```

Only working solution is installing it like this:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node-apple-receipt-verify
```

Comment: Not helpful if there isn't a declaration file in the @types repository.