# Module augmentation / Defining types over non-typed files

Tags: typescript

I need to define types for my current project for the following:

```
import toISOMonthString from 'react-dates/esm/utils/toISOMonthString';
```

The thing is, I tried the basic:

```
declare module "react-dates/esm/utils/toISOMonthString'" {}
```

But I have and error:

```
[ts] Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'react-dates/esm/utils/toISOMonthString' resolves to an untyped module at '.../node_modules/react-dates/esm/utils/toISOMonthString.js', which cannot be augmented.
```

To make the PR in order to solve that should be easy, but I need to solve it locally for now.

Do you have any idea how to type this untyped files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible approach should be to create a `.d.ts` file with the following:

```
declare module 'react-dates/esm/utils/toISOMonthString' {
  import { MomentInput } from 'moment';

  export default function(date: MomentInput): string;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `declare module "react-dates/esm/utils/toISOMonthString'" {}` is being treated as a module augmentation because it appears in another module (a file with a top-level ES6 import or export).  Move the declaration to a separate file so that it is treated as an original declaration of the module.  (This is poorly documented; you can read a bit more about it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17736#issuecomment-338785578).)

Comment: I actually found a solution for this one I can share. First I moved the declaration to another file `.d.ts` and then checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388217/having-error-module-name-resolves-to-an-untyped-module-at-when-writing-cu I could solve the issue with the help of another guy