# How to declare types for javascript submodules from npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

I have JS/TS code base in my project. Some file looks like:

```
import Something from '@some-lib/things/something'; // index.jsx file here

const someFunction = () => {
  // do something with "Something"
};
```

In VS Code and tsc result i have error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module
> '@some-lib/things/something'.
>
> '/Users/user/Projects/project/node_modules/@some-lib/things/something/index.jsx'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> Try `npm install ...` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
> file containing `declare module '@some-lib/things/something';`

I tried to add definitions by creatig file `src/@types/@some-lib/index.d.ts` with this content:

```js
declare module '@some-lib/things/something' {
  const Something: (props: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & {
    size?: number,
    color?: string,
    inline?: boolean,
    className?: string,
  }) => React.ReactElement;

  export default Icon;
}
```

But i get this error:

> Invalid module name in augmentation.
> Module '@some-lib/things/something' resolves to an untyped module at '/Users/user/Projects/project/node_modules/@some-lib/things/something/index.jsx', which cannot be augmented.

Please, help me. How can i declare TypeScript types for JS libraries from npm with subdirectories/submodules ?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.

**If you want to create `d.ts` for js/jsx files from npm-modules you import like this:**

```js
// this is reference to ./node_modules/@some-lib/things/something/index.js
import Something from '@some-lib/things/something'
```

you need to

1. Add `paths` to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
 "compilerOptios": {
    // ...
    "baseUrl": ".", // just require for "paths"
    "paths": {
      "@some-lib/*": ["src/types/some-lib"] // 'src/types' is just for example
    }
  }
}
```

2. Create file `src/types/@some-lib/things/something.d.ts` with content:

```
declare module '@some-lib/things/something' { // equal to import
  const Something = number; // number just for example

  export = Something;
}
```

As far as I understand, your `d.ts` file path in should be the same as the path from `node_modules`, except that its root starts at `src/types/` in example.

I really hope this will help you, good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate of
[Having error "Module 'name' resolves to an untyped module at..." when writing custom TypeScript definition file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388217/having-error-module-name-resolves-to-an-untyped-module-at-when-writing-cu)

Imports should be declared inside the module declaration.

Comment: Sorry for ugly previous comment...
what i need to add to tsconfig for this to work? I add import to declaration and now i have 2 same errors: Could not find a declaration file for module...

Comment: My tsconfig.json looks like this: 

`{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "lib": ["es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ]
}`

Comment: There is no "paths/typeRoots" options in this config. I mean, how can i tell TSC that my npm submodule should be replaced by information from custom `d.ts` file?

Comment: "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/@types"]
    }