# How to locally add types to untyped npm modules in typescript?

Tags: typescript, npm

I know this has been asked an answered elsewhere since at least 2017, but I can't make this work. I have `noImplicitAny: true` in my `tsconfig.json` in my project. I'm trying to use `clamscan` which is neither natively typed nor available in `@types`. My question is not specific to this package.

So when I `import NodeClam from 'clamscan'` in `code.ts` I get the following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'clamscan'. '.../node_modules/clamscan/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/clamscan` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'clamscan';`ts(7016)
```

So I created a `clamscan.d.ts` file with:

```
declare module 'clamscan' {
  // the declarations I use
}
```

I also tried simply `declare module 'clamscan';`. In both cases I get:

```
Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'clamscan' resolves to an untyped module at '.../node_modules/clamscan/index.js', which cannot be augmented.ts(2665)
```

On the other hand, `declare module '*';` is accepted by the compiler but isn't quite what I want (and doesn't solve the original error anyways). So, how can I type an untyped foreign npm module ?

I understand that I can contribute to `DefinitlyTyped` or the `clamscan` package, but the question is about annotating/augmenting the package locally just for my project.

Comment: I suspect typescript can't find your declarations file.  Try putting in at the path `src/@types/clamscan/index.d.ts` or `src/@types/clamscan.d.ts`.  Or editing the `typeRoots` property in your `.tsconfig` to include the path where you have stored it.  I get the "invalid module..." error if I've declared the type after the module has already been imported.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can't make it work anywhere in src/ but I put it in node_modules/@types/clamscan/index.d.ts for now. Gonna play with typeRoots to see if I can do better.

Comment: Every solve this?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell not really, I worked in node_modules/@types, which is not ideal obivously, so I ended up having my type definitions merged in the upstream package, so that it can be useful to others - so I guess problem solved, but I don't have a technical solution for my original issue

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
declare module 'clamscan' {
   import * as Clamscan from 'clamscan';
  export default Clamscan
}
```

or create a single file with only this inside "clamscan.d.ts"

```
declare module 'clamscan' {
       import * as Clamscan from 'clamscan'; // or import Clamscan from "clamscan" or import {Clamscan} from "clamscan" . It depends of how the import is handled
    }
```

If this doesn't work take a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42522751/11941146)

Answer (score 0):

Had to do this for it to work with `digest-stream` :

```
declare module "digest-stream" {
  export default function digestStream(algorithm: string, inputEncoding: string, digestEncoding?: any, options?: any, listenerFn?: any): any
}
```